# Clarification on a basis of the column space of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, for finding $Col(A)$ of the given matrix we reduced it into echelon form and find out the Linearly independent columns in echelon form and correspondings columns in $A$ spans $Col(A)$.

My question is why is this happening? And why not the L.I columns from the echelon form don't span the $Col(A)$, since Echelon form is equivalent to the given matrix.

[This question might sound stupid, but I need to clear my doubts on this, so please don't mind]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true because at each step of the reduction, the linear subspace spanned by the columns of the resulting matrix is equal to the linear subspace spanned by the columns of the previous matrix.

And this is true because the linear space spanned by vectors $\{L_1, \dots, L_n\}$ is the same as the one spanned by the vectors $\{L_1, L_2 - \alpha_2 L_1,\dots, L_n - \alpha_n L_1\}$.

Comment: Okay, What about the latter part?

Comment: Take $\beta_1 L_1 + \cdots + \beta_n L_n$ and try to write it as a linear combination of $L_1, L_2 - \alpha_2 L_1,\dots, L_n - \alpha_2 L_1$ and vice versa. Good exercise!

Comment: so what you're saying is if I have a matrix $A$ and If I reduced it into an echelon form and its basis will also span $Col(A)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I don't think that is correct for example take this matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 &1&-1\\
3 & 6 & 0& 1\\
-1&-2&-2&3
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It will reduce into $\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -3 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Provide the echelon form and the steps to get it to sustain your claim.

Comment: so the 1st and the 3rd columns have 0 in the last coordinate

Comment: That can’t be as making **column operations** you’ll have  one column vector with a non vanishing third coordinates. This is not the case of the matrix you provided.

Comment: I did elementary row operations and got this, this made me ask the question which I posted. I'm confused

Comment: To find the linear subspace spanned by the columns, you have to make column operations. Not row operations.

Comment: Okay, Got it. but for finding rank can I still apply the row operations? Since Rank of A and Rank of A transpose is equal so I think it might work?

Comment: To find the rank yes, as the rank of the rows is equal to the rank of the columns. That is a different question than finding the linear space spanned by the columns, which was your initial question by the way...

Comment: Yes Yes, I got it now. I'm just adding the rank question to clear out my confusion also. Thanks